# Javascript Performance: Multiple script blocks Vs single bigger block

Tags: javascript, frontend, performance

I have observed a weird behavior on IE8(not seen on FF 3.5).
I created 2 sample web pages with only some JS in it.
Page1: 3 JS blocks ( tags) with very small inline JS in them.
Page2: Same JS as above, but all 3 scripts combined in one  block.

I opened the page using dynatrace and observed that for page1, each of the script took ~27-30ms time for parsing/execution. Total time is ~80ms.
For Page2, the combined JS took ~30ms.
Can someone please explain the reason behind this? Is it better to combine the smaller chunks of JS into one?

PS: For all the scripts, the instrumentation time added by dynatrace is negligible.
Firefox 3.5 did not show this behavior. Also the execution time on FF was ~1ms for each of the smaller JS block and ~3ms for the combined JS.

Comment: Are these execution times the same for multiple iterations? If not, I'm assuming it's just something with how IE's allocating memory, and I wouldn't focus too much on a fixed 0.05 second giveup. Unless you have specific needs, you should still probably group things if they're short or move to an external .js if they're large, but still, I'm interested in what _exactly_ causes this.

Comment: yeah.. I repeated this 3 times. The execution times were fairly consistent.

Answer (score 1):

When a browser encounters a script block it has to pause rendering the page while it executes the script in that block.

I'm not sure why this would be so pronouced for IE8 over FF. It could be that the context switch is especially costly in IE8, or that FF may do some work behind the scenes to combine your blocks if it determines it can (I'm only guessing here)

Script blocks also block parallel downloads. If you're downloading images from multiple hostnames, this can happen in parallel, unless you are executing a script block.

In general, I would say that it is best practice to combine your script blocks. Personally, I would recommend you move them into a separate file.

Incidentally, what happens with your metrics when you do move it to another file?

See [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) at Yahoo Developer.

Comment: In my sample pages, there are no images or any other external resources. I just added 3 scripts which access the DOM element and set the handler for the click event using jQuery. I wanted to understand if the browser behaves differently if there are more script tags.