# How do I combine two scripts into one Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two scripts and basically what I want to do is combine them in order to render the result of both in one map.

I already tried to copy/past, but for a reason that I ignore, it's not working (I just start learning so I have basic knowledge in js and gmaps api).

So please before down vote, understand that what I want is just to know if YES or NO there is a way to do such a thing. I tried to search on the net and read Google developer doc but can't find an answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Most of us are not mystics. Therefore you're going to have to show us what you've tried and what in particular didn't work for you.

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible to have two scripts in two different files and get the result of both in one map that's all. I think there's nothing to show

Comment: thank you for the answer, how can we do that please ?

Comment: Please expand your question and provide as much necessary detail as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you use the two scripts. In JavaScript, all scripts you use/import into your html run in the same global scope. So they can access each other's global objects. But keep in mind that the script tags are executed sequentially in the order of appearance.

So:

- You can have as many  tags as you would like in a document.
- The  tags are processed as they are encountered.

How to use Script tag:

```
<script>
  // Inline JavaScript code here
</script>

<script src="external.js"></script>
```

More info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

[multiple versus single script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451156/multiple-versus-single-script-tags)